# jQuery color picker does not pop up after any server-side event is raised

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with a jQuery color picker.

```
var colorCode = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["colorCode"]%>';

$(function () {
    $('#color3').colorPicker({ 
        pickerDefault: "ffffff", 
        colors: [colorCode], 
        transparency: true 
    });
});
```

There is an input text control. Whenever the focus is on that control, a color palette will get displayed and the color can be selected. This was working fine.

I had a checkbox in the same page, and when I check that, a checked changed event will get raised. After this event, the jQuery color picker is not working, i.e. whenever the server side event raised the jQuery color picker is not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you re-rendering the #color3 element? If so, you will need to re-initialize the color picker since the one that had the color picker has been replaced with a new version.

Comment: so once i go to server side, i should reinitialize the color picker..am i right.?

Comment: but i am not rendering the color3 element.whenever any server event raises, the picker is not working

Comment: It would depend what the server side event is doing. Is it reRendering anything on the page, or just executing? Whenever the page changes, it is a good idea to re-initialize the jquery actions.